# keyboard layout indicator in awesome using dbus

Tags: dbus, awesome-wm

I want to use dbus to update my keyboard layout indicator in awesome wm. Here is my func in lua

```
module("keyb")    
function getklayout()
            local fd = io.popen("skb a")
            local layout = fd:read()
            fd:close()
          return layout 
    end
```

and part of rc.lua

```
require("keyb")
keyinc = widget({type = "textbox"})
keyinc.text = keyb.getklayout()
```

I'm not sure what dbus service i need to use to update this widget. My awesome version:

```
   awesome -v
awesome v3.4.9 (Smack)
 • Build: Apr  9 2011 10:40:59 for i686 by gcc version 4.5.1 (builder@apiary.orion.altlinux.org)
 • D-Bus support: ✔
```

need an advise )

Answer (score 1):

I was using skb before. And using timer for periodically checking keyboard state. But this is not good. Now I am using dbus and kbdd for this. First starting kbdd. And add in rc.lua:

```
--- {{{ keyboard indicator
mykeyindicator = widget({ type = "imagebox", align = "right" })
mykeyindicator.image = image(home_dir .. "/.icons/flags/Eng.png")

function mykey_update(...)
    local data = {...}
    local layout = data[2]
    lts = {
            [0] = home_dir .. "/.icons/flags/Eng.png",
            [1] = home_dir .. "/.icons/flags/Rus.png",
    }
    mykeyindicator.image = image(lts[layout])
    return
end

dbus.request_name("session", "ru.gentoo.kbdd")
dbus.add_match("session", "interface='ru.gentoo.kbdd',member='layoutChanged'")
dbus.add_signal("ru.gentoo.kbdd", mykey_update)

--- keyboard indicator }}}
```

Kbdd home page: https://github.com/qnikst/kbdd